# Sizeof() function not working over a constant array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, sizeof

Before starting, I am compiling the program using VS2015 C++ language. The problem is a compiling error when I try to determine the size of two constant arrays. Class involved in the issue:

Header file:

```
#ifndef RACE_H_
#define RACE_H_
class Race
{
    private:
        static const int PILOT_POINTS[];
        static const double TEAM_AWARDS[];
}
#endif
```

Source file:

```
#include "Race.h"
const int PILOT_POINTS[] = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };
const double TEAM_AWARDS[] = { 100000, 75000, 50000, 25000, 15000, 10000 };
```

Part of the errors:

```
sizeof(TEAM_AWARDS) / sizeof(TEAM_AWARDS[0]))
sizeof(PILOT_POINTS) / sizeof(PILOT_POINTS[0]))
```

The compiler says:

> Error 2070 const int[] operand sizeof not valid.
>
> An incomplete type is not allowed.
>
> Error 2070 const double[] operand sizeof not valid.
>
> An incomplete type is not allowed.

Could I use extern to solve the problem? If so, how should I use it?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `const std::vector<int> PILOT_POINTS`? Then you can just use `PILOT_POINTS.size()`

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: You don't specify the size in *declaration*.

Comment: Also `const int PILOT_POINTS[] = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };` is not initializing the array from the class but creating a global array.  You need to change it to `const int Race::PILOT_POINTS[] = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };`

Comment: @CoryKramer: `std::vector::size()` is not a compile-time constant.  `sizeof` is.  Very important if you're using it as a template non-type parameter, or to initialize an enumeration, or as the dimension of another array.

Comment: @CoryKramer, you should make that an answer. It's quite possible that `vector` would solve the OP's question perfectly. I suppose we need to know more about the element count calculation, can the OP demonstrate how they are using the count? In particular, must it be known at compile time?

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point, in which case they could use `std::array` because `std::array::size` is compile time constant, i.e. constexpr

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have *declared* the arrays, but you have not *defined* them at the point you are invoking the `sizeof` operator.

Furthermore, you can't just move your definition to the header, because only integral types may be defined this way:

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment- expression is a constant expression. A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression... (§9.4.2/3)

C-style variable length arrays are not integral, because their length isn't known until they are defined.

To solve this problem, you need to use a length-specifier in the array:

```
#ifndef RACE_H_
#define RACE_H_
class Race
{
    private:
        static const int PILOT_POINTS[10];
        static const double TEAM_AWARDS[6];
}
#endif
```

This is extra hassle, because now you must change the lengths if the array changes sizes, but it's necessary.

Alternately, you can use `constexpr`, and put the entire definition in the header. This way, you can omit the array lengths.

```
#ifndef RACE_H_
#define RACE_H_
class Race
{
    private:
        static constexpr int PILOT_POINTS[]
                = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };
        static constexpr double TEAM_AWARDS[]
                = { 100000, 75000, 50000, 25000, 15000, 10000 };
}
#endif
```

Also, you might try what @CoryKramer suggests in a comment, and use a `vector`.  You'll have a very small run-time cost to initialize it and to look up the size, but that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: If you mess up and put too large a count in the declaration, it will be a silent error and the end of the array will just be filled with zeros.

Comment: That's a good point.  If you choose Door #1, make sure you count correctly, and add a comment to the definition for maintainers.  Door #2 eliminates such opportunity for error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just provide the size in the declaration. From [dcl.array]:

> Except as noted below, if the constant expression is omitted, the type of the
>   identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list array of unknown bound of T”, an **incomplete object type**.

And [expr.sizeof]:

> The `sizeof`
>   operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type [...]

The exceptions for arrays without the constant expression size are when you provide an initializer (e.g. `int a[] = {1, 2}`) or when the array was previously declared with a size. So in this case, you could either provide the size or the initializer the header:

```
static const int PILOT_POINTS[10];    
static const int PILOT_POINTS[] = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };
```

or simply just use a `vector`, so you can initialize it in the source, and get all the other nice advantages of `vector` over raw C arrays:

```
static const std::vector<int> PILOT_POINTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have addressed the fact that you need to define the array. For the sake of completeness, I would mention that your way of getting the size of the array is "[the C version](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/103284/)". C++ has a better way [std::extent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Race
{
    static const int PILOT_POINTS[];
    static const double TEAM_AWARDS[];
};

const int Race::PILOT_POINTS[] = { 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 };
const double Race::TEAM_AWARDS[] = { 100000, 75000, 50000, 25000, 15000, 10000 };

int main()
{
    ::std::wcout << ( sizeof( Race::PILOT_POINTS ) / sizeof( Race::PILOT_POINTS[ 0 ] ) ) << L' '
        << ( sizeof( Race::TEAM_AWARDS ) / sizeof( Race::TEAM_AWARDS[ 0 ] ) ) << L'\n'
        << std::extent< decltype( Race::PILOT_POINTS ) >::value << L' '
        << std::extent< decltype( Race::TEAM_AWARDS ) >::value;
    return 0;
}
```